# Facing issue in composer.json file for an extension

Tags: extensions, composer, json, version, app

I have mentioned in my one of extension in composer.json. Could anyone tell what does it mean. I think it means that the php version should be greater than 7.4.0 but less than 8.2.0 but when i installed it on version 8.1.25 it gave this error -  version has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (8.1.25)
Also If i want to allow  version greater than 7.4.0 and  8.0.0 and greater than that also then what condition to put

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.4.0|^8.2.0",}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **^** symbol in front of the version numbers indicates the package requires a PHP version that is equal to or greater than the specified version, but less than the next major version the same major release.

The **|** symbol between the two versions indicates the "or" condition.

In your specific case, `^7.4.0|^8.2.0`. You should use a PHP version equal to or greater than 7.4.0, but still within the same major release (in this case, PHP 7.x), or a PHP version equal to or greater than 8.2.0 within the same major release (PHP 8.x).

Comment: If i want to allow  versiongreater than 7.4.0 and  8.0.0 and greater than that also then what condition to put

Comment: As I understand your requirement, you allow all versions greater than 7.4.0, including 7.4.1, 7.4.2,...7.4.33, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.3.0, 9.0.0, 9.1.0 and so on. If so, use `>7.4.0`. However, if you still allow `7.4.0`, then use `>=7.4.0`

Comment: It seems you are defining the requirement for your extension for Magento versions that support PHP 7.4, PHP 8.1, or PHP 8.2. If so, you can refer to the condition from Magento core and use this condition: `~7.4.0||~8.1.0||~8.2.0`.

Comment: I want to allow all version greater than 7.4 so should i write [
"require": {    "php": ">=7.4.0|}

Comment: **greater than** 7.4 `"php": ">7.4"`. **equal to or greater than** 7.4 `"php": ">=7.4"`. Note, since there is only one condition, you'll need to remove the `|` symbol after the version number.

Comment: Will it work on all version like 8.0.0 and 8.1.1 and so on

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the previous comment. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371237/facing-issue-in-composer-json-file-for-an-extension/371240?noredirect=1#comment508996_371240

Answer (score 0):

> ^7.4.0 means any version equal to or greater than 7.4.0 but less than
> 8.0.0.
>
> |^8.2.0 means any version equal to or greater than 8.2.0 but less than
> 9.0.0.

So you need to add below changes to allow PHP version 8.1.25, for example:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4.0|^8.1.0|^8.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

^7.4.0 is equivalent to >=7.4.0 <8.0.0

so you should use this in your composer.json

```
~7.4.0||~8.1.0||~8.2.0
```

Comment: You can simply use this condition